# Method does not save received JSON objects to an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have the following method that receives JSON data from an API. The method receives the correct number of objects, recognizes the attributes (offer_title) correctly, but does not save the received/created objects to the "array".

If I check the number of items in "array":

```
2014-09-12 20:57:47.439 stadtklick[1648:514103] the array with offers has: 0 items
2014-09-12 20:57:50.516 stadtklick[1648:514119] received 4 items
2014-09-12 20:57:50.517 stadtklick[1648:514119] Loaded offer: hhh
2014-09-12 20:57:50.518 stadtklick[1648:514119] Loaded offer: ii
2014-09-12 20:57:50.518 stadtklick[1648:514119] Loaded offer: uu
2014-09-12 20:57:50.519 stadtklick[1648:514119] Loaded offer: eeeeEE
```

And why does the method array.count at the end start before I have received all objects?

```
- (NSMutableArray *)defaultPeople {

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString* urlStr = [kBaseURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:kLocations];

NSLog(@"URL: %@",urlStr);

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        [self.offers removeAllObjects];
        NSArray* responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"received %lu items", (unsigned long)responseArray.count);

        for (NSDictionary* item in responseArray) {
            Offer* offer = [[Offer alloc] initWithDictionary:item];
            [array addObject:offer];
            NSLog(@"Loaded offer: %@",offer.offer_title);

        }

    }

}];
[dataTask resume];

NSLog(@"the array with offers has: %lu items", (unsigned long)array.count);

return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dataTask` is a asynchronies task. So the completion block hits after the response comes. But before the completion block hits you are returning `array`. This is not the correct way to do it. Try to pass the `array` within completion block (I'm not saying returning inside the completion block).